# Best Azure service for large no of SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, azure

We have a dedicated SQL Server machine for a SAAS application with about 200+ databases, the server has E5-2620 with 64 GB RAM. Now we want to move all the databases to Azure, so we're looking into the options: we can either go with a Virtual Machine like (DS13 v2) which can support all these databases, or we can use Azure SQL Elastic Pools like Standard with 400 eDTUs.

My question is: in the long run, and from a management and scalability point of view, which option is better? And also will the Standard Elastic Pool with 400 eDTU's provide the same performance as the virtual machine?

One of the major concerns for us is the performance of the SQL databases in Azure, as this is one of the reason to move the whole application to the Azure so that in the future as the no of users grow we can easily upgrade our instances to cater the increased load.